# Why am I getting Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting errors and I don't understand why, I have tried everything I know

The aim is to my final basket and to check out using th pay now function.

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
<body>
<div id="products-wrapper">
 <h1>View Cart</h1>
 <div class="view-cart">
    <?php
    $current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
        $total = 0;
        echo '<form method="post" action="paypal-express-checkout/process.php">';
        echo '<ul>';
        $cart_items = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
        {
           $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
           $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_name,product_description, price FROM products WHERE product_code='$product_code' LIMIT 1");
        
            if( !$results)
                die($mysqli->error);

            $queryResult = array();

            while ($obj = $results->fetch_object())
            {
                $queryResult[] = $obj->product_name;
            }
        
            echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
            echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
            echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj['0']->price.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo '<h3>'.$obj->product_name.' (Code :'.$product_code.')</h3> ';
            echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';}
            
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
            $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_price['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->price.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
            $cart_items ++;
            }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Pay Now" />';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '<span class="check-out-txt"><strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong></span>';

     
?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You can always help yourself by using search.

Comment: What line is giving you the error?

Comment: If you can post error it will be easy to find out issue with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors that I can see. 
in your while loop, you are fetching all your results, one by one, in the temp var called $obj.

```
while ($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$queryResult[] = $obj->product_name;
}
```

inside the loop, you can access all the properties of $obj. For example you can get product_name, and that is ok. 
But after the last iteration of the loop, $obj will be always null, as you can see in http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php 
And of course, at no point $obj is an array, so:

- you shouldnt read $obj as an array, and
- you shouldnt read $obj at all after the loop.

For this, when you try

```
echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj['0']->price.'</div>';
```

you are trying to get the first item of an array that is not an array, so it will fail. 
and in

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
```

or

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_price['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->price.'" />';
```

you will always be accesing a null object, so it will also fail.

the solution will be to change your while loop, so it includes all the code below related to one row in the database.

```
//keep your code until here

 while ($obj = $results->fetch_object())
 {
               // $queryResult[] = $obj->product_name; //probably you dont need this
            // } your loop ends here, but it shouldnt

            echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
            echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["code"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">&times;</a></span>';
            //you dont access $obj[0], but $obj
            echo '<div class="p-price">'.$currency.$obj->price.'</div>'; 
            echo '<div class="product-info">';
            echo '<h3>'.$obj->product_name.' (Code :'.$product_code.')</h3> ';
            echo '<div class="p-qty">Qty : '.$cart_itm["qty"].'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$obj->product_desc.'</div>';}

            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
            $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$cart_itm["qty"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->product_name.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$product_code.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_price['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->price.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_qty['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
            $cart_items ++;
            }
    }//this is the new end of your loop

     echo '</ul>';
    //from here, your code remains the same
```

With this, you will solve the problem you are reporting, but probably you will have to check your code carefully since it could contain some other bugs.